# Using Jquery, create function to determine clicked class

Tags: jquery, html

i'm new to jquery.
I have a map, and some selection images(with color, not outline),
and i need to use checkbox_click to save the checked area.
-> Choose the color on the left side first, and check the map at the right side. then show that color's image on that checked area.

```
<div class="color_area">
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="purple"></div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="hidden_input checkbox_click1" name="mcans1" id="mcans1" value="1" rhandle="yellow">
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden_input checkbox_click1" name="mcans1" id="mcans2" value="1" rhandle="purple">

<div class="click">
  <div class="click_yellow checkbox_click checkbox_click1" id=yellow" handle = "mcans1"  handle_name="mcans1"><img src="images/yellow1.png" id="yellow"></div>
  <div class="click_purple checkbox_click checkbox_click1" id="purple" handle = "mcans1"  handle_name="mcans1"><img src="images/purple1.png" id="purple"></div>
</div>
```

i need to create a function() for determine which color have clicked, and a function() for clear pre-color image when clicked another color.

```
function color_section(color){
    var color_class  = $('div').attr('class');
    var color = "." + color_class;

    if(color == '.yellow'){
        return 1;
    }
    if(color == '.purple'){
        return 2;
    }
}
```

i don't know how can checkbox_click know the color i've click.

```
$('.yellow').click(function(){      
  //Do this first
   $('.checkbox_click1').click(function(){
    //find('img.yellow') then   
       });
});
```

i have no idea what to do. Somebody help me, please..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to click on one checkbox (for example `yellow`), and show the linked image, is that it ? By using jQuery, it's pretty easy :

```
$( ".checkbox_click1" ).on( "click", function() {
    var color = $( this ).attr( "rhandle" );
    var divToShowId = "#" + color;

    $( divToShowId ).show();
});
```

Please see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/868p2/

With `$( this )` inside your callback function, you can access the selected element ; then, you can get the color id and open the div with it. If you want to show/hide depending on the current status, a simple condition will do it.

EDIT : okay, I understand better your problem now ; I edited my fiddle with your HTML code and the JS functions. I slightly updated your HTML, for example by changing color classes for `data-color` attributes, what would be more meaningfull (see [this article](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) about `data attributes`)

I decided to separate the click event on the div from the click event on the checkboxes ; instead of binding an event to the checkbox when the div is clicked, I decided to bind it directly. In order to know if we can do the actions (ie, the checkbox is on the selected div, we have the right to click on it), we will use a `selected` class that we would add to the checkbox itself.

So here is the code :

```
$( ".color_area div" ).on( "click", function() {
    // Choose the color by clicking a div
    // Save in any var you need
    var color = $( this ).attr( "data-color" );

    // Here, we manage the class that will help us to trigger checkboxes click
    $( ".checkbox_click1" ).each( function() {
        var forColor = $( this ).attr( "rhandle" );

        if( forColor == color ) {
          $( this ).addClass( "selected" );   
        } else {
            $( this ).removeClass( "selected" );
        }
    });
});

$( ".checkbox_click1" ).on( "click", function() {
    // Verify it's selected
    if( $( this ).hasClass( "selected" ) ) {
        var color = $( this ).attr( "rhandle" );

        // Clear present imgs
        $( "#" + color + " img" ).each( function() {
            $( this ).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

And the updated fiddle : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/868p2/1/)

Comment: i'm sorry that my fair english:
i need to click `#yellow` first since i have to choose the color, and then click the checkbox_click, it will link to `checkbox_click1#yellow` to find the correct images. i think the html have wrong, do you have any idea? i need to connect the div because i have to save that color on that checkbox_click

Comment: hi, i have a problem in `$(".checkbox_click1").each(function(){});` it can addClass "Selected", but in `$( ".checkbox_click1" ).on( "click", function() {});` it didn't get into `if( $( this ).hasClass( "selected" ) )` I don't know why..

Comment: It should work, please verify the letter case (you say addClass `Selected` (with an uppercase), but you check `selected` (without uppercase) )

Comment: i'm sorry i type wrong here, but it's letter case. it's strange that has add the class but not go inside hasClass

Comment: Please post your code to a fiddle, so I can see what's going wrong

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yoyococo/pKjwS/1/) And please forgive me that i'm not good at coding.. :(

Comment: i guess the problem is i have all same checkbox_click1, as your jsfiddle, if i click yellow, add class yellow, but i checked the second checkbox, it won't have any action. So i think the same with my code, i always check on the no action checkbox, so i can't get into `if($(this).hasClass("selected"))` i just tried `$( this ).removeClass("checkbox_click1");` but not work. if just like what i'm saying, how  can i do that i check one checkbox_click and remove another checkbox_click?

Comment: i have one more question, since i will have 18 of checkbox_click, so i will have 18 of `$(".checkbox_click1").on("click",function(){})` how can i make the code clear?

Comment: i'm sorry, the web developer said don't use this html, he said it hard to use this way, do you have any idea, if i have to change another way?

Comment: i solved this problem and have other bug, would you like to take a look? [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236190/using-jquery-change-display-block-to-none-cant-run-into-block-again)