# Using Jquery, change display block to none can't run into block again

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here, my html.

```
<div class="color_area">
  <div class="blue" data-color="blue"></div>
  <div class="green" data-color="green"></div>
  <div class="red" data-color="red"></div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_click" id="checkbox_click1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_click" id="checkbox_click2" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_click" id="checkbox_click3" value="3">

<div id="clickable">
  <div class="click_blue1 clickable" id="blue"><img src="images/blue1.png" id="blue"></div>
  <div class="click_blue2 clickable" id="blue"><img src="images/blue2.png" id="blue"></div>
  <div class="click_blue3 clickable" id="blue"><img src="images/blue3.png" id="blue"></div>

  <div class="click_green1 clickable" id="green"><img src="images/green1.png" id="green"></div>
  <div class="click_green2 clickable" id="green"><img src="images/green2.png" id="green"></div>
  <div class="click_green3 clickable" id="green"><img src="images/green3.png" id="green"></div>

  <div class="click_red1 clickable" id="red"><img src="images/red1.png" id="red"></div>
  <div class="click_red2 clickable" id="red"><img src="images/red2.png" id="red"></div>
  <div class="click_red3 clickable" id="red"><img src="images/red3.png" id="red"></div>
</div>
```

And here's jquery

```
$('#clickable div img').hide();
$('div.clickable').css('display','none');

$( ".color_area div" ).on( "click", function() {

  var color = $( this ).attr( "data-color" );

        $( "div.clickable" ).each( function() {
            var forColor = $( this ).attr( "id" );
            if( forColor == color ) {

                if( $( this ).css('display') == 'block'){
                    $( this ).hide();
                }

                $( this ).addClass( "selected" ); 
                $( this ).css('display','block');
             }else {
                $( this ).removeClass( "selected" );
            }
        });
    });


    $( "div.clickable" ).on( "click", function() {

        if( $( this ).hasClass( "selected" ) ) {

            var color = $( this ).attr( "class" );
            $( this ).find('img').show();

             $( "." + color + " img" ).each( function() {
                 $( this ).remove();
             });
        }
    });
});
```

The click_red class always in front of `div#clickable`, that's why i have to display none or block. I just can choose the color once, because they all change to `display:block`, then the click_red class stay in front of click_blue and click_green, i can't click anymore. I want to click color to do `addClass( "selected" )` and `$( this ).css('display','block');`  again. Is anybody have any ideas?

Edit : OK, i have a map, it has 18 region images, they're `display:none` before people click the `div#clickable`, people need to choose the color first,  then click the clickable area to decide which color of images to show on the map. Just like colouring, i can choose different color to click different region and show the right color's images.

Here the fiddle [click me](http://jsfiddle.net/yoyococo/jfxmv/)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I still couldn't get it completely. Still I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/Rr9bm/) explaining a few things working. What else do you need please update in comments.
    `.hide() and .show()` is used instead of `disply:none / block` thing.

Comment: i'm sorry that i'm not good at english. my problem is `$( this ).hide()` then it's never go down the code to `addClass( "selected" )`
here's [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yoyococo/jfxmv/)

Comment: i want to do is when people click another color, the present color image won't hide.

Comment: like? click green greens shown, click red reds also shown(green still remains and never disappears again.)??? like this??

Comment: @user3017670 see the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/Rr9bm/1/) then. you just need to remove else condition from the previous fiddle. Hope this is what you expected.

Comment: i'm sorry, because of my problem is can't click back to the blue and green actually. The red color image always on top.

Comment: I don't get what you saying, can you please clear requirements?